# How can i improve inserts times in a big table?

Tags: mysql, database

We have the following data structure in a MySQL table which basically logs user actions on pages

```
id int
page_id int
user_id int
action_type enum(6)
date_created datetime`
```

We have the following indexes:

```
id Primary key
user_id-page_id-date_created unique
page_id-user_id-date_created
user_id
page_id-date_created
```

Our issue is that this table currently has 125 million rows and it's growing at a rate of 0.8 million a day which makes the inserts take about 2 hours to complete. 
The inserts are made through 3 queries that select data from 3 other tables. What could we do to improve this time?
Should we drop mysql and try other database solutions?

**L.E:** Based on your feedback I am trying to give more info.
First of all the tables are MyISAM and these inserts happen once every night in a cron job and we do not delete any data from them.
Here is how i handle the inserts. I will refer to the big table as big_table and each of the 3 tables will be content_table because they are similar in structure. The explains will be for the largest of the 3 tables which has around 108.5 million. First i get the id from which i should start inserting using php. (I'm ok with the 3 minutes for the non-indexed query to get it)

```
SELECT id FROM content_table WHERE date_created > "2012-04-18" ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;
+-----------+
| id        |
+-----------+
| 107278872 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (3 min 15.52 sec)

EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM content_table WHERE date_created > "2012-04-18" ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | content_table    | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)
```

And then using this id i do the following

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO big_table (user_id, page_id, type, date_created) 
SELECT user_id, page_id, IF (is_admin,"admin_action","action") as type, created_time FROM content_table WHERE id >= "107278872";
```

Here's how the explain for the select looks like

```
EXPLAIN SELECT user_id, page_id, IF (is_admin,"admin_action","action") as type, created_time FROM content_table WHERE id >= "107278872";
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | content_table    | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 777864 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I've also tried it in phpmyadmin and got times of around 0.004s so i think it's the inserts that take time and not the data fetching. All i know about the server is that it is a quad core xeon @ 2.4 ghz and 16 GB of ram but I do not know anything about storage (will come back as soon as i have that info). And the data is not used for logging only we need to have statitistics like which users were most active on pages, various groupings etc and the user can specify any interval for these.

Comment: Do you know what's taking the time? Is it the selecting from the other tables or the insert itself?

Comment: If it serves just as a log, maybe you should think about putting it in just plain files instead of a database. Depends on how you intent to use the data, though.

Comment: drop indexes before inserts and rebuild them after

Comment: What storage engine is being used?

Comment: changing database is not a solution if you didnot even clear about your problem.

Comment: how are you inserting? Bulk inserts or individual insert statments?

Comment: as you are frequently updating or inserting the data into your table then i think you should not use indexes over it,because it takes extra time

Comment: If I'm interpreting this right, you haven't specified what hardware you're using, what's the load on your server, what engine you're using and it takes 2hrs to complete 800k inserts, which amounts to 110ish inserts per second, which isn't that terrible for a mechanical hard drive in transaction mode.  If I'm wrong in anything, please correct me.

Comment: @Uriel_SVK tried that and times dropped with about 30 minutes. I was wondering if there is anything we cand do get it down even more.

Comment: @N.B. i updated the question, i don't think we are in transaction mode since we use MyISAM

Answer (score 3):

You could:

1. EXPLAIN PLAN on the queries you run on the 3 other tables to see if they're properly indexed.  TABLE SCAN should be eliminated.
2. Add indexes to those three other tables for each WHERE clause in the queries.
3. Partition the data by day, week, month, or some other suitable mechanism so you can move the oldest data out to a reporting/warehousing solution.
4. You could see if a trigger solution could help you.
5. Profile the database and monitor network traffic to see where the time is being spent.

All relational databases will suffer from having to deal with too much data.  Your first thought should not be to drop MySQL; it should be figuring out what your archiving strategy needs to be.  You have to decide exactly how much of that data is needed in your transactional store at a given time.

Comment: Also 6. Check the various db/session and memory settings like buffers, etc and tune. 7. Consider increasing memory available to the db engine.

Comment: You think using triggers on the 3 tables that would also insert data in the big table when inserted in them would be faster?

Comment: The total time might be the same, but the difference will be smaller, more frequent inserts.  The perceived time will seem less.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many factors affecting the insert such as

- Engine type
- Indexes
- how the data is inserted etc.

First of tell us how you are inserting the data, second thing which storage engine is using for table then we can further optimize you insert query, in general I can say unnecessary index means slow insert rate.

For more explanation on the speed of inserts [read this article of dev.mysql for insert speed.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html)

Comment: The storage engine is MyISAM. I updated the question with detailed info about how the inserts are made.

Answer (score 0):

How are you inserting them ? You can only have a certain number of transactions per second looping querys like this

```
//start loop
insert into table values (1) 
//end loop
```

will be MUCH slower than

```
//start loop
//fill a variable 
//end loop
insert into table values (1),(2),(3),(4) // where (1),(2),(3),(4) are values filled by the loop
```

(note that you cant insert too many values like this, try it with your data, I usually find 200 or so is a pretty good value)

You dont have a huge amount of index's so i dont think they are cauing problems, phpmyadmin shows the index size, Check what that is compared to the total table size - that may give you an idea of if its storing too much